# Redirect & SEO (SSL Redirect)

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

So I bought an SSL for my website, and to redirect the HTTP to HTTPS, I use the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,NE]
```

It works great. No problem. But the issue is when I do some basic Speed Tests & SEO test, theres always an error saying things similar to "disable redirect for better speed, seo".

But If i delete .htaccess redirect, there would be issues with HTTP/HTTPS

How can i solve this problem? Is there any other way to make the SSL work without redirecting?

*Just In Case Information; I use Godaddy Linux Server.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All `src`/`href`/`action` html attributes must contain a relative paths. Also look for `<link rel="canonical" href="https://...">` and `<base>` tags.

Comment: Like Deadooshka suggests, it sounds like you are linking to the non-canonical URL in various places.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your .htaccess file to solve SSL problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

if RewriteEngine already "On" then no need to "On" again. I hope this will work perfectly.

Comment: This is basically exactly what is in the question, and does not answer it in any way. The answer is in the first comment in fact: just use HTTPS links directly, so that no HTTP->HTTPS redirections are necessary.